# HashSet and multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, concurrency, java-7

I work on Java 7.

I want to know if the method `contains` is thread-safe on HashSet object.

The HashSet is initialized by one thread. Then we wrap the HashSet with unmodifiable collection (`Collections.unmodifiableSet`). After initialization, multiple threads call only the method `contains`.

When I read the Javadoc, it's unclear for me.

On [HashSet Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) we can read

> This class implements the Set interface, backed by a hash table (actually a HashMap instance).

...

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized.**

And on the [HashMap Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/HashSet.html), we can read:

> Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (**A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more mappings**; merely changing the value associated with a key that an instance already contains is not a structural modification.)

For me, this means the method `contains` is not a structural modification.

So multiple call to the method `contains` is it thread-safe?

If it's true: Is it guaranteed on all implementation of JVM (like IBM JVM)?

Comment: It doesn't matter if your thread is not making structural modifications: if some other thread is making structural modifications, you need to synchronise *all* access from *any* thread, including calls to `contains`.

Comment: Even if we use `Collections.unmodifiableSet` at initiaization of HashSet? In fact, we are sure that we use only the `contains` method in our case. in order to be clear: all thread which use the HashSet (after initialization) use only the method `contains`

Comment: "if some other thread is making structural modifications". If you immediately wrap the set in an unmodifiableSet at construction, no other thread is making structural modifications.

Comment: OK. We immediately wrap the set in an unmodifiableSet at construction. I confirm. It's clear for me. Thanks Andy, I need a external advise to be sure. Is it independent of JVM implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, there can be no concurrency race (and thus conflict) solely between read operations. Concurrency problems arise between read and write operations. So, multiple read operations interleaved are always thread-safe (if we assume that such a notion of thread-safety is well defined).

Now, there is one more case where there might be a concurrency issue and this is during the initialisation of the data structure, since this can be considered the only modification (write operation) in your case. In order to make sure that all the subsequent `contains()` invocations will see the fully initialised Set, you have to make sure that it's correctly initialised. This concept is defined as "safe-publication" in Java and you can read more about it [here](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/TSM03-J.+Do+not+publish+partially+initialized+objects) or in the book ["Java Concurrency in Practice"](http://jcip.net/) book.

To conclude, `Collections.unmodifiableSet()` publishes the result in a safe way through a `final` field. **So, yes you can be sure that all `contains()` will see the fully initialised `Set`**